# UWP: write file to disk using the simple and fast PInvoke calls CreateFile and WriteFile

Tags: vb.net, uwp, windows-10, pinvoke, desktop-bridge

We have an unmanaged memory C++ dll that generates video data. The user interface is in UWP VB. 
I need to write the video data to the disk. The user gives the location to write from a file picker and this path and file name is passed to the dll. Using CreateFile and WriteFile the data will be written to disk.

This is the VB code

```
<DllImport("mycplus.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)>
Public Function MainFrozen(ByVal EvF() As UInteger) As UInteger
End Function


Private Async Sub btnSaveAs_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnSaveAs.Click
    Dim savePicker = New Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker()
    savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary
    savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Video Files", New List(Of String)() From {".bin"})
    savePicker.SuggestedFileName = gVideoFileName
    Dim file As Windows.Storage.StorageFile = Await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync()

    If file IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim fileName As String = file.Path
        Dim d(0 To 15) As UInt32

        d(0) = VIDEO_FILE_WRITE
        d(1) = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(fileName)
        d(2) = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(gAuthorName)
        d(3) = gReserved

        d(8) = MainFrozen(d)
    Else
        'txtDeubg.Text = "Operation cancelled."
    End If
End Sub
```

And the following is the C++ code

```
extern "C" __declspec (dllexport) ULONG __stdcall MainFrozen(PULONG ptrEv)
{
    ULONG eve = ptrEv[0];

    switch (eve)
    {
    case VIDEO_FILE_WRITE:
        SaveScanVideosToFile((LPCSTR)ptrEv[1], (LPCSTR)ptrEv[2], ptrEv[3]);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}


ULONG SaveScanVideosToFile(LPCSTR   lpFileName, 
                            LPCSTR  lpAuthorName,
                            ULONG   reserved)
{

    HANDLE hFile;
    ULONG bytesWritten;
    ULONG n;

    hFile = CreateFile(lpFileName, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    for (n=0; n<gScanVideoCnt; n++)
    {
        WriteFile(hFile, ScanVideos[n].pImg->Bcine.pCineMem, SCAN_VIDEO_MEM_SIZ, &bytesWritten, NULL);
        WriteFile(hFile, ScanVideos[n].pImg, sizeof(IMG_TYPE), &bytesWritten, NULL);
    }
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is I am unable to write to any location other than: Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
 I.e C:\Users\ravi\AppData\Local\Packages\2d6e339b-614b-4161-8c7d-3570f07fc01f_2ygbv2t9jdb9y\LocalState\

At other locations, CreateFile fails with access denied.
However using the .net file functions I am able to write other test files to almost all locations in my PC in the latest creators edition of win10, which is most welcome and heartening.

The question is: what security attributes should be set so that CreateFile will succeed and write to all location like the native .net file functions do?

There could be workarounds like marshal the entire data to managed memory or writing the file to the ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder and then moving it using vb.net calls. But nothing like making CreateFile succeed.

PS: Our app is a side loaded one for enterprise use only and we do not mind if it fails windows stores test. (our customers are trusting us from “windows NT” days :-)

Comment: This is how the UWP sandbox works.  To access any folder other than Appdata the user needs to pick the folder using the UWP FilePicker and save it as a StorageFolder object which contains a security token.  You can later grant access to that folder using the token so the user doesn't have to do the picker each time, but they have to do it at least once.

Comment: Since it's going to be sideloaded, you can get creative with a workaround.  The UWP app can use Launhcer to run an external script.  You can also send an HTTP request to another app.

Comment: CreateFile is *forbidden* in a UWP app.  File access must be vetted against the capabilities requested in the appx manifest.  Using the WinRT provided api is best, but you can use [CreateFile2()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449422(v=vs.85).aspx) if you have to and only need to access the app folders.

Comment: @HansPassant Initiatives like Desktop Bridge are indicative that Microsoft is realizing and rectifying mistakes it did to backward compatibility in the name of evolution. I am optimistic the ban on CreateFile will be lifted very soon!

Comment: Hi, have you added to the package manifest the extensions of the file you are trying to save? I had a similar problem once for a sideloaded uwp app and I was not able to save files to a custom folder until I added those extensions in manifest...

Comment: @Filipppo When using a file picker no such declaration seems to be required. Files can be written to "almost" any place including USB pen drives. However only Async file function seem to succeed on such file objects. Not able to access the file through traditional win32 calls using the file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Help from Microsoft forum got this working.[click here for the full thread](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aaa27ed3-5d72-4c9a-9270-9d2f5af8e72c/uwp-write-file-to-disk-using-the-simple-and-fast-pinvoke-calls-createfile-and-writefile?forum=wpdevelop)

Basically Cast the file object to IStorageItemHandleAccess and call Create to obtain a file HANDLE. Then use WriteFile and Close in unmanaged code.

Here is the code:

```
<ComImport>
<Guid("5CA296B2-2C25-4D22-B785-B885C8201E6A")>
<InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>
Friend Interface IStorageItemHandleAccess
    Function Create(ao As Int32, so As Int32, o As Int32, oploc As Int32,
                    ByRef ptrHandle As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Interface
```

' just 2 lines of extra code in your function to get the HANDLE which works magic!

```
Dim storageHandleIface = DirectCast(file, IStorageItemHandleAccess)
Dim myfileHandle As IntPtr
Dim res = storageHandleIface.Create(&H120116, 2, 0, 0, myfileHandle)    ' WindowsStorageCom.h
```

Comment: This should be just a stop gap arrangement. I was assured in the future update of Windows 10 access would be more direct (using CreateFile2)